# how to update the records from one table to another

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

```
1)NewAccount
2)Deposit
```

NewAccount table contains fields as:

1)accNum as primary key
2)amount

Deposit table contains fields as:

```
1)accNum as foreign key
2)DepositAmount
```

My question is if I click on one button it should insert all values to the deposit table as well as it should add that amount to the amount field of NewAccount table.

Here is an example:

if amount field of NewAccount has 500.00
if I add deposit amount of rs 400 .then amount should update to rs.900 in NewAccount table of amount field

Comment: Please tag with the correct product! Is it SQL Server or MySQL? which version?

Answer (score 0):

Create update trigger on NewAccount Table, such that once you update your NewAccount Table it should trigger update on Deposit , set depositAmount = ammount

Comment: i want to make simple banking software which only creates new account, inserting deposit as well as withdraw of ammount. and finaly search for total individual balance of customer can u please help me to do this please give me the er diagram dfd and modules

Comment: can any one help me please

Answer (score 0):

```
    INSERT INTO NewAccount (accNum, ammount)
    SELECT accNum, DepositAmmount
    FROM Deposit a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM NewAcount b where b.accNum=a.accNum)

    UPDATE c
    SET c.ammount=d.DepositAmmount + c.ammount
    FROM NewAccount c
    JOIN Deposit d on d on c.accNum=d.accNum
```

Comment: string update = @"update na
set na._InitialAmmount = na._InitialAmmount+da._DepoAmmount 
from NewAccount na
    inner join Deposit da on
        na._AccNum = da._AccNum
    where da._AccNum = na._AccNum";

Answer (score 0):

Create Insert trigger on Deposit Table, when you insert record in Deposit table, trigger will be invoked and NewAccount amount will be updated with respect to accNum.

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER updateamount AFTER INSERT ON Deposit
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE NewAccount set ammount = ammount + NEW.DepositAmmount where accNum = NEW.accNum;
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```